# Wha tif the size of state is larger than the flink memory size?

Tags: apache-flink

I am wondering that the size of state is larger than the flink's memory size.
Since the state is controlled by the Flink App's APIs by defining `MapState<K,V>` in the code level, the state is possible to store large size of values (which is over than memory size such as 100Gb,200Gb).

Can it be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in reading about [State Backends](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/state_backends/)

> The HashMapStateBackend holds data internally as objects on the Java heap

HashMapStateBackend will OOM your task managers if your `MapState`s are too big.

> The EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend holds in-flight data in a RocksDB database that is (per default) stored in the TaskManager local data directories

> [...] Note that the amount of state that you can keep is only limited by the amount of disk space available. This allows keeping very large state, compared to the HashMapStateBackend that keeps state in memory. This also means, however, that the maximum throughput that can be achieved will be lower with this state backend. All reads/writes from/to this backend have to go through de-/serialization to retrieve/store the state objects, which is also more expensive than always working with the on-heap representation as the heap-based backends are doing.

EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend will use the disk, so you have more capacity. Note that it is slower, but that caches could help alleviate some of that slowness; the configuration of which I suggest you look at ([in Flink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/state_backends/#memory-management) using [RocksDB's mecanism](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Block-Cache#caching-index-filter-and-compression-dictionary-blocks))